# Search Builder - Undefined array key 'contact_is_deleted

Tags: search-builder, php8

When I run a search using Search Builder i get the error above - also occure when editing a smart group criteria.  Using Advanced search does work.

The PHP is Selector.tpl.php on lines 113 & 114

Wordpress install Version 5.66.0      PHP 8.1   Upgraded on 14/10

Answer (score 0):

Search Builder is actually a deprecated part of CiviCRM, as the preferred replacement is Search Kit.

See documentation here: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/searching/searchkit/what-is-searchkit/

In general about this sort of Smarty notice: they are notices rather than errors so they are not harmful, but they are annoying and indicate that an error *might* arise when upgrading to a future version of PHP (in previous versions of PHP they were not visible at all). So the CiviCRM community [has been working hard to address them](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pulls?q=is%3Apr%20smarty%20notice). Since Search Builder is deprecated it's sort of a last priority, but you are most welcome to jump in and help out. Using any of those PRs as a guide you could create a PR to fix this particular notice if it bugs you enough .

Comment: Thanks for the response - it helps but wouldn't know where to start with PR's - guess this is a Pull Request